# Is it possible to write a code for DROP the first partition without specifying the name?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning

The pseudocode would be something like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE sql_store.sale_mast13 DROP PARTITION FIRS_VALUE(PARTITIONS)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  But you can get the name from `information_schema.PARTITIONS`.  See `GatherPartitionInfo()` in http://mysql.rjweb.org/demo_part_maint.pl.txt .  For more on partitioning, see the parent page: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint